# How to write a script that places every line in a file as a separate element in an array?

Tags: linux, putty

I'm using PuTTY and I need to write a script that sends each line of a file into an array. Here's what I have but it is not working correctly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..29}; do programmers[i]=0; done

while read current
do
        echo $current
        programmers[i]=$current
        ((++i))
        sleep .1
done</1111/module9/programmers | cut -d \. -f 2
```

Comment: define *not working*. Any error?

Comment: When I type 'echo ${programmers[@]}' it just says the array is filled with a bunch of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using a strange amalgamation of a for and while loop. You should have only used the while loop. The secondary problem is the subshell caused by piping into `cut`.

Here's the correct way of doing it:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray myarray < myfile
```

Works on Bash 4.2+

Comment: My instructor gave me part of the code I'm supposed to use for the script:

#!/bin/bash

while read current
do
     echo $current
     sleep .1
done</1111/module9/programmers

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have to use the part of the code my instructor gave me to complete the script.